# MATLAB - Perform operation on matrix indices without a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, indices

It's been a little while since I've done matrix operations in MATLAB, so please forgive me if this is easily solvable.

I have some NxM matrix `A`, and I would like to perform an operation on the column indices of `A`. I know how to do this using a `for` loop, but since I'm using MATLAB I'd like to make use of MATLAB's ability to do operations on matrices fast.

Suppose I have a function called `myFunc`. Is there a way to do the following without a `for` loop (such as with matrix multiplication):

```
for i=1:M
    A(:, floor(i*myFunc())) = A(:, i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just replace `i*` by `(1:M).*`, like this:

```
A(:, floor((1:M).*myFunc())) = A(:,1:M)
```

Note that `.*` does element-wise multiplication instead of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Is this OK?

```
A(:,floor([1:M]*myFunc())) = A(:,1:M)
```

coz I don't know if your myFunc is also dependent on i.

Comment: How would `myFunc()` be dependent on `i`?

Comment: If myFunc(i) for different i returns different value, then we'll need to make sure myFunc([1:M]) also return a vector. And use .*.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov The question said nothing about what is the parameter and what will be returned by myFunc(), it can return a scalar or a vector, if a scalar is returned, then there is no need for .* ; if a vector is returned, need to make sure it is the same size as 1:M. Else using .* will cause error