# MATLAB - work directly with indices of a matrix without using a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I saw this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163814/matlab-perform-operation-on-matrix-indices-without-a-for-loop) but he's operating only on one index. I need to operate on both column and row indices without using a for loop. 
Is there a way to do this:

Let M (a,b) be the matrix and the size be the one in the parentheses. I want to manipulate each element as exp( (m-n)^2)

Comment: Yes, there are very many ways.  But without you being more explicit about what you want to do and showing your prototype code, the closest to an answer you'll get is the first sentence in this comment.

Comment: Alright. Let M (a,b) be the matrix and the size be the one in the parentheses. I want to manipulate each element as exp( (m-n)^2).

Comment: Behold -- as soon as you clarified your requirements useful answers appeared !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `bsxfun`

```
M = exp( bsxfun( @minus, (1:a)', 1:b ).^2 );
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty awesome command. I'm using it and it makes things so much easier.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to [using `bsxfun`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895238/1714410), here, would be using `meshgrid`:

```
>> a = 5; b = 4; % Some example dimensions
>> [n, m] = meshgrid(1:b, 1:a)

n =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4


m =

     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5

>> M = exp((m - n).^2);
```

Note that this example is mainly instructive rather than practical - the `bsxfun` solution is faster and consumes less memory - but this shows how you *could* generate matrices of matrix subscripts.

Comment: +1, although the memory footprint becomes prohibitive for larger `a` and/or `b`.

Comment: This is slower than `bsxfun` and consumes more memory. Just sayin'.

Comment: @EitanT: Yes, it is slower for large a/b, but I wanted to show the OP how they *could* generate matrices of the indices.